# В чем причина допущенной коммуникативной ошибки?

Tags: коммуникативные-требования

Сергей Довлатов пишет: «Подгорный в 1963 году посетил легендарный крейсер «Аврора». Долго его осматривал. Беседовал с экипажем. Оставил запись в книге почетных гостей. Написал дословно следующее: "Посетил боевой корабль. Произвел неизгладимое впечатление!"»  Фраза Подгорного производит комическое впечатление. Но в чем истоки этого впечатления? Каковы причины коммуникативной ошибки? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: В 1963-м году, Николаю Викторовичу было уже 60 лет! А ведь подобные перлы случаются и у молодёжи, сплошь и рядом.
В общем: "Войдя в комнату, сапоги мои стояли около кровати".

Answer (score 2):

Коммуникативная ошибка — это неверная, ошибочная интерпретация сообщения получателем, сбой в общении. Можно понять запись следующим образом: **я посетил** боевой корабль,  и при этом **я произвел** на окружающих неизгладимое впечатление.

Причина ошибки — употребление глагольных форм прошедшего времени мужского рода, которые при отсутствии в предложении подлежащего могут отнесены и к лицу мужского пола, и к предмету мужского рода (кораблю).

Answer (score 0):

Во втором предложении субъект (деятель) не указан, форма глагола в нем – такая же, как и в первом предложении: совпадают род, число, время (и также место: в начале). В результате получается, что «произвел» – тот же, кто «посетил»: Подгорный произвел неизгладимое впечатление.
Причина коммуникативной ошибки в следующем. Неверный смысл возникает в такой грамматической конструкции (кто – на кого?), которая обычно является абсолютно однозначной (в отличие от конструкции «кто – кого?»). Такого  результата Подгорному удалось добиться тем, что он все в той же второй фразе опустил, не замечая этого пропуска, и субъект (кто, что произвел) и косвенный объект (на кого произвел). Т.е. пропущены два необходимых, предопределенных конструкцией элемента. Остался, по сути, только предикат «произвел», и он автоматически соотносится с субъектом первого предложения. Вот и получается… «неизгладимое впечатление».